# Return default row without NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns a single row

```
SELECT
  'abcde' type,
  NVL(SUM(something),0) value
FROM
  tableA a,
  tableB b
WHERE
  a.id=b.id;
```

In this case it returns the following if the condition satisfies,

```
TYPE   VALUE
-------------
abcde   100
```

If the condition not satisfied, it won't returns any row.I need to return a default row in this case, like,

```
TYPE   VALUE
-------------
abcde   0
```

I tried using WHERE NOT EXISTS but in this case I have to include the large query in WHERE NOT EXISTS(my_large_query).

```
SELECT
  'abcde' type,
  NVL(SUM(something),0) value
FROM
  tableA a,
  tableB b
WHERE
  a.id=b.id
GROUP BY
  'abcde'
UNION
SELECT
  'abcde' type,
  0 value
FROM
  dual
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      'abcde' type,
      NVL(SUM(something),0) value
    FROM
      tableA a,
      tableB b
    WHERE
      a.id=b.id
  );
```

Is there any other way I can use instead? If there any performance issue occures if I use `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: So you want the query to always return at least one row? Then simply use **UNION** without NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: But using UNION will always give him the default row, which he does not want, in case there is real data. I thought CASE would do, but I could not reach a working solution so far.

Comment: He didn't mention that. In that case, he needs an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: would not an outer join fall in the same problem - always bringing the default row ?

Comment: @Veverke Of course, it will. Else, using NOT EXISTS is must. I am waiting for OP to clarify if he ALWAYS wants a row.

Comment: Yes.. always need to return row.

Comment: @Eeepi Then you could use an outer join, see my answer. Remember, outer join will produce rows from outer joined table even if the rows do not match the join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select one record with 'abcde', so select this from dual. You get the sum in a subquery.

```
select 
  'abcde' type,
  nvl(
  (
    SELECT SUM(something)
    FROM tableA a
    JOIN tableB ON a.id=b.id
  ), 0) as value
from dual;
```

UPDATE: If you want more aggregates from the tables, you could do this with three subqueries, but it would be ineffective to do about the same query thrice. So you could use an outer join instead. As your tables' aggregates are totally unrelated with the dual table, however, this looks a bit strange, but well, the query *is* strange, consisting of an outer-cross join :-)

```
select 
  'abcde' as type, 
  nvl(sum_current, 0) as sum_curr,
  nvl(sum_previous, 0) as sum_prev
from dual
left join
(
  select 
    sum(data_current) as sum_current,
    sum(data_prev) as sum_previous
  from tablea a
  join tableb on a.id = b.id
) on 1 = 1; -- cross-outer joining
```

And here is the same without the `1 = 1` dummy ON clause. We select the type 'abcde' along with the aggregations and use this for the join.

```
select 
  'abcde' as type, 
  nvl(sum_current, 0) as sum_curr,
  nvl(sum_previous, 0) as sum_prev
from (select 'abcde' as type from dual)
left join
(
  select 
    'abcde' as type,
    sum(data_current) as sum_current,
    avg(data_prev) as sum_previous
  from tablea a
  join tableb on a.id = b.id
) using (type);
```

Choose whichever query you like better.

Comment: Can I use this if I have 4 fields in select?

Comment: You mean more aggregations as in `SUM(something), AVG(somethingelse), MAX(anothercolumn)`? No, that would be different. Do you want a solution for that?

Comment: I mean `SELECT 'abcde' type, NVL(SUM(data_current),0) value1,VL(SUM(data_prev),0) value2 ..` like this

Comment: The subquery should be in the FROM clause then (i.e. become a derived table). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i just proposed the same solution as the first one mentioned by Thorsten so it's gone... but you have substantially altered the question by the comments here. The question should be changed in my view.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner is that `from dual;` at last line required?

Comment: No, that's a typo. Sorry. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a FULL OUTER JOIN, if i understand the question

```
SELECT
  'abcde' type,
  NVL(SUM(something),0) value
FROM tableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b ON a.id=b.id
GROUP BY 'abcde'
```

Comment: If there aren't any value in tableA and in tableB this query return 0 rows. He want however 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **[LEFT|RIGHT]OUTER JOIN**.

For example, using standard EMP and DEPT table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> SELECT d.deptno,
  2    NVL(e.empno, 0) empno
  3  FROM emp e
  4  RIGHT OUTER JOIN dept d
  5  ON e.deptno       = d.deptno
  6  AND d.deptno     IN (30,40);

    DEPTNO      EMPNO
---------- ----------
        10          0
        20          0
        30       7499
        30       7521
        30       7654
        30       7698
        30       7844
        30       7900
        40          0

9 rows selected.
```

In above output, you can see that there is an additional row for **DEPT = 40** using **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**.

Try this query:

```
SELECT 'abcde' type,
  NVL(SUM(something),0) value
FROM tableA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB b
ON a.id=b.id
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: This is not giving the result as expected. As you mentioned it fetches, multiple records which I could not handle in group by also.

Comment: @Eeepi There is no reason for the query to fail. Anyway, I have added a query for you to try. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Eeepi, hi!

> Seems to me we have here a XY problem. And you may try to solve this
>   using PL/SQL since you've tagged the question as Oracle related.

But, responding strictly to your question: 1. yes we can solve you issue using pure SQL; 2. yes the query with `not exists` will gain some performance loss, because there's nothing free.

We need to consider that impact on the performance in this case is insignificant.
For example, using of `UNION` keyword (in your example) will be a 1000 times more expensive - so, please use `UNION ALL` always if you don't want Oracle engine to sort and compare all rows in the query.

The query you need is:

```
WITH
 t AS
 (SELECT 'abcde' TYPE
        ,nvl(SUM(something), 0) VALUE
    FROM tableA a
        ,tableB b
   WHERE a.id = b.id)
SELECT *
  FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM t

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 'abcde',  0 
          FROM dual
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t)
       )
```

Comment: This is same as including two `WHERE NOT EXISTS(my_complete_query)` right?

Comment: Yes, this is the same. I think the answer of @Thorsten Kettner would be more suitable for your intensions if you need exactly one row each time.